# CSS- Injecting and aligning images above certain words in (any) html text without ruining the text flow

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to dynamically (with content script) inject images above text in basically any page, and keeping the text normally aligned. The words I inject the image to have a span around them with a certain attribute, and my script(content script of chrome extension) wraps that span with another span(the parent in my css) that has the img (wrapped up in its own span) as well.

The issue (a CSS issue) is when i inject the images the text lining of the text gets ruined.

You can see it all much more clearly in https://jsfiddle.net/wyfumrx6/2/

the words 'a Good' aren't lined with the rest of the text.

Here's what i do now, using inline-flex and flex-direction:

HTML example:

```html
<a href="https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Good-Cup-of-Tea" style="/* line-height: 57px; *//* height: auto; */font-size: 150%;font-family: Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;/* height: 55px; *//* display: inline-flex; */">
  <span id="div0" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0" style="">
        <span id="span0" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/1/12313.png"
                class="aui_header_images"></span>
  <span aui-symbol="14907" aria-describedby="span0" accesskey="Shift + E">How
        </span>
  </span>
  <span id="div5" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0">
        <span id="span5" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/7/7194.png"
                class="aui_header_images"></span>
  <span aui-symbol="17982" aria-describedby="span5" accesskey="Shift + E">to</span></span> <span id="div6" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0"><span id="span6" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/3/32751.png"
                class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="15410" aria-describedby="span6" accesskey="Shift + E">Make</span></span>
  a Good <span id="div7" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0"><span id="span7" class="aui_top_in_page"><img
                src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/2/2429.png" class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="13621 12324 17511" aria-describedby="span7" accesskey="Shift + E">Cup of Tea</span></span>
</a>
```

With CSS (injected as well):

For the span wrapping the img(inside a span) and the text(also inside its own span):

```css
.aui_top_in_page_parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999999;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

For the inside span wrapping the img only:

```
.aui_top_in_page {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: regular;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  align-items: center;
}
```

see it all much clealy with the result here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wyfumrx6/

I want the line, the words, to stay in a straight line while the images are above the 'marked' words, and that that images will have enough margin from the text line above so that it's clear which word the img is refering to.

Comment: The image size should eventually be determined by the font size of the text, but for now they are of fixed height and width. I updated the fiddle by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use vertical align bottom if you remove the 1% top and bottom margin:

```css
.aui_top_in_page_parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999999;
  margin: 0 1%;             /* change this to side margin only */
  vertical-align: bottom;   /* add this */
}

.aui_top_in_page {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: regular;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99999999;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Good-Cup-of-Tea" style="/* line-height: 57px; *//* height: auto; */font-size: 150%;font-family: Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;/* height: 55px; *//* display: inline-flex; */" class="container">
  <span id="div0" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0" style="
">
    <span id="span0" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/1/12313.png" class="aui_header_images"></span>
    <span aui-symbol="14907" aria-describedby="span0" accesskey="Shift + E">How</span>
  </span>
  <span id="div5" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0">
    <span id="span5" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/7/7194.png" class="aui_header_images"></span>
    <span aui-symbol="17982" aria-describedby="span5" accesskey="Shift + E">to</span>
  </span>
  <span id="div6" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0">
    <span id="span6" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/3/32751.png" class="aui_header_images"></span>
    <span aui-symbol="15410" aria-describedby="span6" accesskey="Shift + E">Make </span>
  </span>
  a Good
  <span id="div7" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0">
    <span id="span7" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/2/2429.png" class="aui_header_images"></span>
    <span aui-symbol="13621 12324 17511" aria-describedby="span7" accesskey="Shift + E">Cup of Tea</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od8st0wh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution..

I make few changes in HTML and CSS file as below..

add `span` tag `<span class="aui_top_in_page_parent">a Good</span>`

and some changes in css file.

```css
.aui_top_in_page_parent{
       display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* position: relative; */
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 5px;
}
a{
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.aui_top_in_page{
  
   font-size:14px; 
   font-weight:regular;
   overflow:visible; 
   padding:0px 0px 0px;
   color:#fff;
   -webkit-border-radius:7px;
   -moz-border-radius:7px;
   border-radius:7px;
   -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
   -moz-background-clip:padding;
   background-clip:padding-box;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   text-align:center;
   text-decoration:none;
      z-index:99999999;
   align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Good-Cup-of-Tea" style="/* line-height: 57px; *//* height: auto; */font-size: 150%;font-family: Gotham, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;/* height: 55px; *//* display: inline-flex; */"><span id="div0"  class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0" style="
"><span id="span0" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/1/12313.png" class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="14907" aria-describedby="span0" accesskey="Shift + E">How</span></span> <span id="div5" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0"><span id="span5" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/7/7194.png" class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="17982" aria-describedby="span5" accesskey="Shift + E">to</span></span> <span id="div6" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0"><span id="span6" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/3/32751.png" class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="15410" aria-describedby="span6" accesskey="Shift + E">Make</span></span><span class="aui_top_in_page_parent">a Good</span>  <span id="div7" class="aui_top_in_page_parent" tabindex="0"><span id="span7" class="aui_top_in_page"><img src="http://www.arasaac.org/repositorio/thumbs/10/50/2/2429.png" class="aui_header_images"></span><span aui-symbol="13621 12324 17511" aria-describedby="span7" accesskey="Shift + E">Cup of Tea</span></span></a>
```